# SVN- Folder Structure- Maintaining the code

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

We are maintaining a huge list of ETL scripts and reports based on the scripts for many customers. Currently the scripts are not in to any versioning mechanism. We are trying to implement versioning using SVN. We have identified couple of options for that. One with Per customer multiple branch and trunk and other one is single trunk, branch with the customer folders inside.

We wanted to have two sets of code one for production and development. The following are the options we have came up with.

**Option-1**

```
SVN-Dev
   trunk/
      Customer1/
          ETL/
          Web/
      Cusomer2/
            ETL/
          Web/
      Customer3/
          ETL/
          Web/
      …
   tags/
      Customer1/
      Cusomer2/
      Cusomer3/
      …
   branches/
      Cusomer1/
      Cusomer2/
      Cusomer3/
      …
```

**Option-2**

```
SVN-Dev
   Customer1/
      trunk/
      tags/
      branches/
      …
   customer2/
      trunk/
      tags/
      branches/
      …
   customer/
      trunk/
      tags/
      branches/
      …
```

Please let me know which would be a better options. I would also want to know the merits and demerits of each structure.